# Hide / show div using one button in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to hide one element and show the other when when button is clicked and switch around when it is clicked again.

I came up with something like this but this isn't going to work...

```js
jQuery("#wcvat-toggle").click(function() {
  jQuery("#excltaxout").show();
  jQuery("#incltaxout").hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="wcvat-toggle">
  <span id="incltaxout">Including Tax</span>
  <span id="excltaxout">Excluding Tax</span>
</a>
```

However this will always show the `#excltaxout`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make this work - and assuming that one of those elements starts hidden - you can simply call `toggle()` on them both at the same time. This will invert their `display` states.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $("#wcvat-toggle").click(function() {
    $("#excltaxout, #incltaxout").toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
#excltaxout { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="wcvat-toggle">
  <span id="incltaxout">Including Tax</span>
  <span id="excltaxout">Excluding Tax</span>
</a>
```

Comment: ohh man, as simple as that! I wasn't adding the display: none to one of those and it was changing the display to both of them... Sorry for that simple question, having hard time learning! You are amazing. thanks.

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Comment: Yes, but you really shouldn't. External stylesheets are always preferable.

Comment: Great, got it working with external stylesheet. Ain't it amazing when everything works as it should? :) Enjoy your evening!

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery's `.toggle()`:

> Display or hide the matched elements.

```js
$("#wcvat-toggle").click(() => {
  $("#incltaxout").toggle();
  $("#excltaxout").toggle();
});
```

```css
#incltaxout {display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="wcvat-toggle">
  <span id="incltaxout">Including Tax</span>
  <span id="excltaxout">Excluding Tax</span>
</a>
```

Note however that this only works if one element is hidden by default, if not you will hide/show both at once.

Comment: Just saw, that I basically posted the same as Rory... My internet is even to slow to load answers in in time :-/

Comment: I really appreciate your will to help me. Rory was first so I accepted his answer, however a cheeky upvote from me to you :) Enjoy your evening.

Comment: That's the way to go :-) 
Thanks a lot! Have a nice evening yourself!